# Gnome Disks is crashing when creating encrypted partition

Tags: partitioning, 15.04, encryption, 15.10, dmcrypt

In Ubuntu 15.10, I have a second hard-drive and I'm trying to create an encrypted partition using the included GUI for partitioning disks. But upon doing that Gnome Disks is crashing.

This is a clean install of Ubuntu 15.10. This happened to me with a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 as well. It does work without issues in Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: Still broken in 16.04